# Constant speed for wheel of any radius when setting speed in radians per second?

Tags: math, physics, box2d

In box2d physics engine I can set a motor speed for a joint on my wheel in Radians/Second.

What would be an expression I could set the speed to so the final actual "speed" of the wheel would be the same regardless of wheel radius.

Presently, I'm setting the Wheel speed  as a constant, wheelSpeed = 20.  But this has the effect of making large wheels faster than small ones.  I want the radius to be used in figuring the radians/sec for the motor speed so I will get the same effective speed regardless.

So, if it was a small wheel, it would have to turn much more often than a large one.

I think I need to do something like 2 * PI  * Radius / 180 * Speed? Or something similar, but I can't figure it out exactly.

I want to based the wheel motor speed (in radians/sec) it so the final "speed" of the wheels is constant regardless of size of the wheel.

Answer (score 6):

There are `2 PI` radians in a full circle and your circle length is the circumference (`2 PI R`).

So, if you want a constant speed of the circumference running past a point, you need a radial speed of:

`Y = 2 PI / 2 PI R`

or:

`Y = 1/R`

In other words, make the value a factor of the inverse of your radius.

Answer (score 2):

If v is speed, w is frequency, and r is radius: the equation is `v = w * r`, or `w = v / r`. So just take your desired velocity, divide by the radius of the wheel, and set that as the angular velocity.

Answer (score 1):

The circumference of the wheel is proportional to the radius, therefore in order to keep the radial velocity in linear units/second constant, divide by the increase in radius.

For example, at radius R, the radial velocity is 1 rad/sec. Then if you increase the radius to 2R, the radial velocity should be 1/2 rad/sec.

Comment: Slight nitpick on phrasing: you divide by the radius, not the increase in radius.

Comment: No, you divide by the increase, the ratio that is, between the original radius and the new radius